# Powershell stop-process not killing Logstash

Tags: powershell, process, logstash

I am writing a powershell script that allows Logstash to run for a certain amount of time and then stops the program by process id. Here is a basic version of the code:

```
$logstashFilepath = "C:\Users\emckenzie\Downloads\logstash-5.3.2\logstash-5.3.2\bin\logstash.bat"
$logstashArguments = "-f C:\users\emckenzie\Downloads\logstash-5.3.2\logstash-5.3.2\test_loader.conf"

$logstashprocess = Start-Process -FilePath $logstashFilepath -ArgumentList $logstashArguments -PassThru
$logstashid = $logstashprocess.Id

Write-Host $logstashid

Start-Sleep -s 60

Stop-Process $logstashid
```

In this test case Logstash only writes from stdin to stdout. When I run this program the output looks like this:

```
17120
Stop-Process : Cannot find a process with the process identifier 17120.
At C:\Users\emckenzie\Documents\Loaders\testLoader.ps1:13 char:13
+ Stop-Process <<<<  $logstashid
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (17120:Int32) [Stop-Process], ProcessCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand
```

Is this a problem in Logstash or Powershell?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like Logstash is starting another process. You should be able to witness this with task manager or better, SysInternals Process Explorer. If it turns out that is the case you can likely start Logstash, wait a moment, and then grab the new process ID by it's name if it is consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I figured out what programs I need to stop Logstash (java and jruby) but after reading more I don't think it's a good idea to go around killing logstash without letting it stop safely. There's risk of data loss, and Elasticsearch also relies on Java and JRuby. There has to be an official way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using NSSM to start Logstash as a service instead, and I control NSSM through Powershell.

```
# You must configure testlogstash using the GUI NSSM provides
$logstashFilepath = "C:\Users\emckenzie\Downloads\nssm-2.24\nssm-
2.24\win64\nssm.exe"
$start = "start testlogstash"
$stop = "stop testlogstash"

$logstashprocess = Start-Process -FilePath $logstashFilepath -ArgumentList 
$start -PassThru

Start-Sleep -s 60

Start-Process -FilePath $logstashFilepath -ArgumentList $stop
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments on the original post I believe there is a solution for you. If you know the program running that needs to stay running until the job is finished:

```
$logstashprocess = Start-Process -FilePath $logstashFilepath -ArgumentList $logstashArguments -PassThru
$logstashid = $logstashprocess.Id

$Global:IsRunning = $false

Do {
    $process = Get-Process -processname "NameOfProcessHere"
    If ($process){
        $IsRunning = $true
    }else{
        $IsRunning = $false
    }
} While ($IsRunning -eq $true)

Stop-Process -processname "$logstashid"
```

Let me know if this is helpful, or if i'm not understanding the question.

Comment: See, the problem is that there's more steps to a shutdown than just stopping the process.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/shutdown.html#_what_happens_during_a_controlled_shutdown
Personally I don't think it's possible, unless there's a command for Windows to shut Logstash down safely other than Ctrl^C

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean after reading the article in that link. I think you are correct that there won't be a way to do this without possibly losing important data if it is forced to close.